# how to implement back pressed activity in fragment in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, exit

I have develop application which has many fragment activity like home, gallery, songs, other so my issue is when i play audio in songs fragment and then I press back button to get exit from the application but audio playing continuously so I want to code on back press button but I don't know how to work and which method should override like in activity finish() method in on back pressed method

my code

```
*public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_aarti_fragment, container, false);

        btnplay=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btnplay);
        btnstop=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btnstop);
        seekbar=(SeekBar)v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                        mp.stop();

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Stop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);

                        try
                        {
                            mp.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        } catch (IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Aarti Currently not playing",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

            }
        });


        btnplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.pause();
                    btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finalTime = mp.getDuration();
                    startTime = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    if(oneTimeOnly == 0)

                       {
                         seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                         oneTimeOnly = 1;
                       } 
                    seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);

                    handler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);

                }
                else
                {   btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
                    mp.start();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finalTime = mp.getDuration();
                    startTime = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                    if(oneTimeOnly == 0)

                      {
                         seekbar.setMax((int) finalTime);
                         oneTimeOnly = 1;
                      } 
                        seekbar.setProgress((int)startTime);

                        handler.postDelayed(UpdateSongTime,100);
                }
            }
        });
        return v;*
```

}

Comment: Want to exit from application or from your current fragment?

Comment: u can override onKeydown(...) and check for keyevent.

Comment: I want to exit from current fragment and redirect to home activity

Comment: override `onBackPressed` in `FragmentActivity` class and do what yo want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of overriding back button etc, you should use fragment lifecycle methods.

You can override onStop() method in fragment to release media resource or stop.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    mp.release(); // or pause or stop.
    Log.i(TAG, "onStop");
}
```

To control back button, in your activity class

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do something, show toast message to confirm or go to another activity
}
```

Comment: how to use back button method in fragment like toast "press back again "

Comment: you can override backbutton in activity class which holds fragment, override it in activity class and put your case there.